# Amount of "jumping" numbers from 101 to 10^60?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say number is "ascending" if its digits are going in ascending order. Example: 1223469. Digits of "descending" number go in descending order. Example: 9844300. Numbers that are not "ascending" or "descending", are called "jumping". Numbers from 1 to 100 are not "jumping". How many "jumping" numbers are there from 101 to 10^60?

Comment: Do you expect answers that simply tell you how many such numbers there are?

Comment: I don't expect one to begin coding only to give me answer, but any idea would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea: instead of counting the jumping numbers, count the ascending and descending ones. Then subtract them from all the numbers.

Counting the ascending/descending ones should be easy - you can use a dynamic programming based on the number of digits left to generate, and the digit you have placed in the last position.

Comment: The OP should also beware of double counting, as apparently "9844300" is 'descending', so '555' might be both ascending (i.e. really nondecreasing) and descending (i.e. really nonincreasing.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Is it enough to count only descending/ascending ones? It seems to me that amount of ascenlding numbers = amount of descending numbers...

Comment: You should probably count both. They might be equal if you allow leading zeros, but you still have to figure out how to handle duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

I'll describe how to count the ascending numbers, because that's easier. Going from that, you could also count the descending ones and then subtract the combined amount from the total amount of numbers, compensating for duplicates, as indicated by Ivan, or devise a more complex way to only count jumping numbers directly.

### A different approach

Think about the numbers sorted by ending digit. We start with numbers that are 1 digit long, this will be our list

```
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 1
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 2
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 3
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 4
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 5
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 6
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 7
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 8
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 9
```

To construct numbers with two digits ending with 6, we can use all numbers ending with 6 or less

```
1 // Amount of numbers ending with 1 with 2 digits
2 // Amount of numbers ending with 2 with 2 digits
3 // Amount of numbers ending with 3 with 2 digits
4 // Amount of numbers ending with 4 with 2 digits
5 // Amount of numbers ending with 5 with 2 digits
6 // Amount of numbers ending with 6 with 2 digits
7 // Amount of numbers ending with 7 with 2 digits
8 // Amount of numbers ending with 8 with 2 digits
9 // Amount of numbers ending with 9 with 2 digits
```

Writing these side by side, can see how to calculate the new values very quickly:

y  a // y, a, and x have been computed previously
x (a + x)

```
1 1  1   1 
1 2  3   4
1 3  6  10
1 4 10  20
1 5 15  35
1 6 21  56
1 7 28  84
1 8 36 120
1 9 45 165
```

### A simple Python program

Iterating over one such column, we can directly produce all values of the new column, if we always remember the last computation. The `scan()` function abstracts away exactly that behavior of taking one element, and do some computation with it and the last result.

```
def scan(f, state, it):
  for x in it:
    state = f(state, x)
    yield state
```

Producing the next column is now as simple as:

```
new_column = list(scan(operator.add, 0, column))
```

To make it simple, we use single digit numbers as starting point:

```
first_row = [1]*9
```

Seeing that we always need to feed back the new row to the function, can use scan again to do just that:

```
def next_row(row):
    return list(scan(operator.add, 0, column))

def next_row_wrapper(row, _):
    return next_row(row)

>>> [list(x) for x in scan(next_row_wrapper, [1]*9, range(3))] # 3 iterations
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45], [1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84, 120, 165]]
```

As you can see, this gives the first three row apart from the first one.

Since we want to know the sum, of all numbers, we can do just that. When we do 1 iteration, we get all ascending numbers until 10^2, so we need to do 59 iterations for all numbers until 10^60:

```
>>> sum(sum(x) for x in scan(lambda x, _: next_row(x), [1]*9, range(59))) + 10
56672074888L
```

For the descending numbers, it's quite similar:

```
>>> sum(sum(x) for x in scan(lambda x, _: next_row(x), [1]*10, range(59))) + 10 - 58
396704524157L<
```

### Old approach

Think about how the numbers end:

From 10 to 99, we have two digits per number.

There are

- 1 that ends in 1
- 2 that end in 2
- 3 that end in 3
- 4 that end in 4
- 5 that end in 5
- 6 that end in 6
- 7 that end in 7
- 8 that end in 8
- 9 that end in 9

All of these numbers act as prefixes for numbers from 100 to 999.

An example, there are three numbers that end in `3`:

- 13
- 23
- 33

For each of these three numbers, we can create seven ascending numbers:

- 133
- 134
- 135
- 136
- 137
- 138
- 139

It is easy to see, that this adds three numbers for each of the seven possible ending digits.

If we wanted to extend numbers ending on 4, the process would be similar: Currently, there are 4 numbers ending on `4`. Thus, for each such number, we can create 6 new ascending numbers. That means, that there will be an additional 4 for all of the six possible ending digits.

If you have understood everything I've written here, it should be easy to generalize that and implement an algorithm to count all those numbers.

Comment: I'm afraid you've made mistake in your example: 877 and 977 are descending, 878, 879, 978 and 979 are jumping...

Comment: @Rail Oh, I got confused there. I fixed it.

Comment: @Rail I have also added a new part plus some code, that should probably work.

Answer (score 1):

Non-jumping numbers:

- `69 choose 9` (ascending numbers of size ≤ 60)
- `+ 70 choose 10 - 60` (descending numbers of size ≤ 60)
- `- 60 * 9` (double count: all digits the same)
- `- 1` (double count: zero)
- `=` 453376598563

(To get jumping numbers, subtract from total numbers: 10<sup>60</sup>)

Simple python program to compute the number:

```
# I know Python doesn't do tail call elimination, but it's a good habit.
def choose(n, k, num=1, denom=1):
  return num/denom if k == 0 else choose(n-1, k-1, num*n, denom*k)

def f(digits, base=10):
  return choose(digits+base-1, base-1) + choose(digits+base, base) - digits*base - 1
```

Ascending numbers: select 9 positions to increment the digit, starting with `0`.

Descending numbers: pretend we have a digit `10` which is used to left-pad the number. Then select 10 positions to decrement the digit, starting with `10`. Then remove all the choices where the 10 selected positions are consecutive and not at the end, which would correspond to digit sequences with a leading 0.

Since all numbers whose digits are all the same will be produced by both descending and ascending algorithms, we have to subtract them.

Note that all of these algorithms consider the number 0 to be written with no digits at all. Also, all numbers ≤ 100 are either ascending or descending (or both), so there's no need to worry about them.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `69 choose 9` for the ascending numbers and `70 choose 10` for the descending numbers?

Comment: @phant0m, yes, of course, they are 60-digit numbers. oops.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `-1` at the end? When you do `-60`, you're already removing all zero variants from the descending numbers, not all but one.

Comment: @phant0m: there are 61 zero variants, because the empty string is also present, and it represents a descending number. The empty string is also present in the ascending numbers. This is all because all leading zeros are eliminated, so the empty string represents 0.

Comment: Oh, right 61 is the last starting position for the 10 consecutive delimiters. I always confuse this, I thought I needed to add 10 to get the index where it ends, and 61 + 10 would have been 71, i.e. out of range. My bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you count 321 as descending or do you count 000000321 as jumping?

Hint for the answer:  the number of ascending numbers with 59 digits will be something like (69 choose 10) because you have to choose which points in the number are between differing digits.

Comment: Zeros from the left side of the number are usually neglected so 321 is of course descending.